# GetTemplateChild returns null when dependency property has RelativeSource binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, relativesource

I have created a custom control, `MyTextBox`, that inherits from `TextBox`. It has a style associated with it that contains a namned control:

```xaml
<Style x:Key="{x:Type MyTextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type MyTextBox}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyTextBox}">
                <!-- ... -->
                    <SomeControl x:Name="PART_SomeControl" />
                <!-- ... -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`MyTextBox` has a dependency property that, when set, propagates its value to `SomeControl`:

```cs
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    // ...

    public static new readonly DependencyProperty MyParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MyParameter",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(MyTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(object), MyParameterChanged));

    private static void MyParameterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var me = (MyTextBox)d;
        var someControl = (SomeControl)me.GetTemplateChild("PART_SomeControl");
        someControl.SetValue(SomeControl.MyParameterProperty, e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

This works fine when doing a simple binding, like this:

```xaml
<MyTextBox MyParameter="{Binding}" />
```

But when I use a more fancy binding using RelativeSource, like this:

```xaml
<MyTextBox MyParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
    FindAncestor, AncestorType=ParentView}}"
```

the method `me.GetTemplateChild()` returns `null`. That is, `SomeControl` cannot be found.

Why?

One observation I have made is that, when it has a `RelativeSource`, the `MyParameter` dependency property is set first of all dependency properties. That is, if I do something like this:

```xaml
<MyTextBox
    OtherParameter="{Binding}"
    MyParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
        FindAncestor, AncestorType=ParentView}}"
```

the `MyParameter` property is (strangely) set before `OtherParameter`. Using the simple binding they are set in the same order as declared, just as expected.

*(As you can see, my code has been stripped from unrelevant stuff. Hopefully, I have included all that is important.)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely it is being set before the template is applied. There are a few ways you could work around that:

- Call [ApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.applytemplate.aspx) before `GetTemplateChild` to force the template to load.
- Use [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `DispatcherPriority.Loaded` to delay the operation until later.
- Allow `MyParameterChanged` to fail if there is no template, and repeat the logic in [OnApplyTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (you should be doing this anyway, in case the template is replaced after load (as in a Windows theme change).

It looks like you're just passing on the value to a child element. Have you considered using an attached property with value inheritance?

As for why it fails for your `RelativeSource FindAncestor` binding, and not the raw DataContext binding, I think this comes down to the fact that `DataContext` itself is an inherited property. Hypothetically, assume the order of operations is this:

1. Parent receives DataContext property
2. Parent adds child
3. Child evaluates MyParameter
4. Child applies template
5. Child inherits DataContext from parent

In the first case, (`MyParameter="{Binding}"`), step 3 fails to update `MyParameter` because it doesn't yet have a DataContext to bind to, so `MyParameterChanged` is not called and there is no exception. After step 5, when the child's DataContext is updated, it re-evaluates `MyParameter`, and by that point the template exists so the property change handler works.

In the second case, you are specifically looking up the DataContext property of the parent, which *does* exist, so `MyParameterChanged` *is* called at step 3 and fails because the template isn't applied yet.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not actually looking for a work-around but for an explanation of the behavior. Btw, I'm currently using your third option :)

Comment: @TorbjörnKalin I added a possible explanation to the answer.

Comment: Excellent explanation and good alternatives and work-arounds. I've learned a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Override OnApplyTemplate method and call GetTempladeChild inside it.
I solved this problem by reading this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179105/How-to-access-Control-Template-parts-from-Code-Beh

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this:

```
<MyTextBox MyParameter="{Binding}" />
```

is only the same as this:

```
<MyTextBox MyParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
FindAncestor, AncestorType=ParentView}}" />
```

if the `MyTextBox` control is in a view named `ParentView` which has its `DataContext` property set. If that is the case, then it really shouldn't cause any problems like you are describing. I can therefore only assume that you are trying to access the `SomeControl` object via the `MyParameterProperty` before the UI has been initialised.

You can test this by adding a handler for the `Loaded` or `Initialized` events. Put a break point in there and an additional one in your `MyParameterChanged` handler and see which order they get raised in. It's worth noting that `Dependencyproperty`s can be set from `Style`s or inline XAML *before* the objects are initialised in the UI.

Comment: Actually, `ParentView` is an ancestor of the control that `MyTextBox` is in. So no, they are not the same (sorry I didn't make this clearer). The reason I mentioned both bindings was to point at the different results.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood then... you said that your `RelativeSource Binding` didn't work, but now you say that it points to a different location to the plain old `{Binding}` path, so of course that wouldn't be the same. Either you have an incorrect `Binding.Path` value and an error should appear in the Output Window in Visual Studio if this is the case, or you are trying to access the property before the `SomeControl` has been initialised.

Comment: The binding works fine and I've got no binding errors. It's getting the template that isn't working - when using a (completely) different binding

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ApplyTemplate();` right after `InitializeComponent();` (usually in constructor) works for me. Override the `OnApplyTemplate()` method & call the `GetTemplateChild` here.

ex:

```
        private TextBox PART_TextBox;
        private RepeatButton PART_UpButton;
        private RepeatButton PART_DownButton;

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            PART_TextBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as TextBox;
            PART_UpButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_UpButton") as RepeatButton;
            PART_DownButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_DownButton") as RepeatButton;
        }
```

This way the `OnApplyTemplate()` should be called before setting any dependency properties.